# Rails: Dynamic session domain and sharing session between subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, subdomain, white-labelling

I have an interesting case. I'm working on white-labeling functionality for a Rails 2.3 application and have problems with setting up dynamic session domains.

So, each white-label should have own domain: company1.com, company2.com, company3.com. More over each of them should have a support for subdomains and sharing the session between them.

I.e. test1.company1.com, test2.company1.com, company1.com <= should share a common session; test1.example.com, example.com <= should share a common session but different from company1.com .

In the common case (for a single base domain) it's done this way:

```
file:production.rb
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.company1.com'
```

If I want to support multiple domains I'll have to set this config option dynamically based on the accessed site domain. I'm currently trying to accomplish it in this way:

```
file:environment.rb
require 'dispatcher'
module ActionController
  class Dispatcher
    def set_session_domain
      tld_size = SubdomainFu.tld_size+1
      host_name = @env['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[-tld_size,tld_size].join('.')
      ActionController::Base.session = { :domain => ".#{host_name}" }
    end
    before_dispatch :set_session_domain
  end
end
```

However the above code does not work.

Have you done something similar successfully or do you have any idea where the problem/solution could be?

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: I was able to get this code working.  Can you indicate what is not working?  Have you tried printing "#{host_name}" to the log at each step to see if you are setting the correct value?  My guess is that you are not setting the proper value for the :domain option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ActionController::Base.session is not going to work, because it is used only when initializing the rack middleware handling the sessions, therefore only when booting your app. In order to make the above code work you should use

```
@env['rack.session.options']
```

Have a look here for an example:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41306